# Is there any documentation on how to implement "Passport Azure AD" in Nest.Js?

Tags: passport.js, nestjs, passport-azure-ad

Is here someone that knows how to implement the "Azure AD" Passport Strategy into Nest.js?
I couldn't find any documentation abut this particular strategy.

Thank you.

Comment: The docs for Nest show how to implement a basic JWT and HttpBasic strategy with passport, but from there you should be able to work with the passport module in general and change which strategy you are working with. [This blog post](https://dev.to/nestjs/authentication-and-sessions-for-mvc-apps-with-nestjs-55a4) shows a Passport Local strategy in a bit more detail and may also be helpful

Comment: Thank you so much, @JayMcDoniel. I will have a look at this blog post.